# Синонимизация [тайл]ов

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки:

- [tile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tile) (16 вопросов)
- [тайл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb) (4 вопроса)

Надо бы их синонимизировать.

Есть ещё [tilemap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilemap) (16 вопросов), но я не уверен, что это относится туда же.